# Angular 2 - Multiple requests updting same compoent

Tags: angular

I have simple text box to search in angular 2 and I have deployed it on AWS. When me and other person from other machine type something in same text box at a same time then same value gets updated for both of us.
E.g this is what i am typing
[Typed from my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBD9S.png)

But my friend from other machine can see same value in his text box without he typing anything.

Both are different http request then why this is happening?

------------------------------Solved------------------------------------

Application was using BrowserSync which was syncing all textbox and click events in sync. So disabled it. This BrowserSync npm gets plugged in automatically if you start angular from their default angular2 project.

For default angular2 app,you can access BrowserSync UI from 3001 port.

Comment: Is your application using any real-time library? :) Angular is client side JS framework. What you are describing is impossible.

Comment: can you post some code for the same as it should not happen if u are not using third party libs

Comment: Application was using BrowserSync which was syncing all textbox and click events in sync. So disabled it. This BrowserSync npm gets plugged in automatically if you start angular from their default angular2 project.